# Vue.js disable blank comments

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, frontend

Usually, when Vue.js hides an element through v-if, a comment is left in its place.

Vue file:

```html
<div v-if="true">Hello</div>
<div v-if="false">world</div>
```

Output:

```html
<div v-if="true">Hello</div>
<!--  -->
```

Is it possible to disable appearance of this comment?

Desired output:

```html
<div v-if="true">Hello</div>
```

Comment: What is the reason you're trying to get rid of this? Is it because you end up with a long list of comments or something? If you have a long list of `v-if`'s then it may be better to just use a `computed` and dynamically display the items you want to display then you wont end up with any comments

Comment: @maxshuty reason: more beautiful code on the client. I just really want to destroy them and reduce them to atoms. They are really ugly.

Comment: Sure, but your client isn't looking at your code in dev tools, and if they are then things should already be minified and uglified :P

Evan You has commented on this subject: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5117 - it actually helps `vnode` diffing to have them...

Comment: @maxshuty, found interesting [solution](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5117#issuecomment-434197624) in this issue. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this solution was noted in the comments on the original post, but I figured I'd share for anyone missing the comments!

If appears that if you use

```
<template v-if="true">
    <div>Hello</div>
</template>
<template v-if="false">
    <div>World!</div>
</template>
```

Then the blank comments will not be inserted!

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5117) in the vuejs repo.
one of the comments that I think would be useful says:

> v-if is usually used for elements in a relatively stable node structure, rendering it to empty comment tags makes vnode lists diffing more efficient as the lists are more "stable", and it avoids some edge cases when elements are not keyed. In your case it doesn't seem to cause any real issue other than small inspection annoyance, so unfortunately I don't think we would change this behavior.

> For virtual scrolling lists, it maybe a better idea to use a computed property to return a subset of the items that needs to be rendered, e.g. v-for="item in displayedItems" instead of using a v-if on each item.